# How to use relative path for a file using distributed testing

Tags: jmeter

I have requirement where I need to run the jmeter testplan using master-slave configuration, with the testplans and datafiles being located in different folder structure. (for example: /projects/sample.jmx and /datafiles/file1.txt) I have tried the beanshell option with fileserver.class. But It did not work, as we know the relative path holds good from where we execute the test plan from the master (Note, the path of the datafiles are same as in master and slave. Please advise any other option to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand what is your problem. Given you have the same directory structure on masters and slaves you have 2 options:

1. Use relative path like `../datafiles/file1.csv`
2. Use full path like `/datafiles/file1.csv`

Relative path doesn't necessarily mean that the data file(s) need to be located at the same folder as test plan(s), you can use file located anywhere, the only difference is that full paths always start from root - `/` and relative paths always start from the folder where .jmx file lives.

See [ABSOLUTE PATH VS RELATIVE PATH IN LINUX/UNIX](http://www.linuxnix.com/abslute-path-vs-relative-path-in-linuxunix/) and [Using CSV DATA SET CONFIG](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG) guides for more details.